# ContainsKey error for metadata field in DD4T and Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, dd4t

In the multimedia comp, the metadata field 'alt' has value and I have the following code to read it. It gives run time error "**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**" and the error is at 'alt' field.

```
@if (comp.Fields.ContainsKey("logo_image"))
{
<img id="siteLogo" class="siteLogo" src="@comp.Fields["logo_image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].Multimedia.Url" alt="@comp.Fields["logo_image"].LinkedComponentValues[0].MetadataFields["alt"].Value"
..

}
```